# Use Intent Activity in RecyclerView and get position ID

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I created six of CardView and linked them to RecyclerView , how when press on cardview postion[2]

I want to make every card view and guest a move to another activity

**this my  code**.

```
public class MyMovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyMovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    MyMovieData[] myMovieData;
    Context context;

    public MyMovieAdapter(MyMovieData[] myMovieData,MainActivity activity) {
        this.myMovieData = myMovieData;
        this.context = activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_item_list,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final MyMovieData myMovieDataList = myMovieData[position];
        holder.textViewName.setText(myMovieDataList.getMovieName());
        holder.textViewDate.setText(myMovieDataList.getMovieDate());
        holder.movieImage.setImageResource(myMovieDataList.getMovieImage());



        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, myMovieDataList.getMovieName(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity2.class);//////////////// //this line //////////////////////// I want to position id
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: How I use this ?

Answer (score 0):

you already have `int position`, just make it `final` and then you may use it inside `onClick`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ...
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, myMovieDataList.getMovieName(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            // would be better to pass item id or name, much better approach
            intent.putExtra("itemId", myMovieDataList.getMovieId());
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to extract position for each element in order to make its own intent. @snachmsm

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to achievie, I've jsut gave you the line which pass clicked position to new `MainActivity2` instance. fit this for your needs, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @snachman is perfectly right. But, it is not preferred by google. Use the method given below.

1. Create a new interface with name `RecyclerViewItemClickListener.java`
2. Add method `void onClick();` to it;
3. Add that to the constructor of the adapter.
4. After adding the constructor, add it to your activity by implementing the interface
5. Add it in the activity by `new RecyclerViewItemClickListener`
6. Now in the activity, add the code to start the activity.
   Hope it helps